# Passing info back to parent (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, composer-php, overlay, coronasdk

I'd thought this would be simple but I've been combing the web trying to solve it for days.

What I'm aiming to do is have a button which brings up a small pop-up which can then be used to select a new image for the original button. The way I was hoping to do it was to set the original buttons sprite frame to composer.getVariable("buttonState") but I'm not sure how to pass back the command to update the original sprite.

Currently in main.lua i'm using

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
composer.setVariable("buttonState", 1 )
composer.gotoScene( "scene_game")
```

Then in scene_game.lua there is the sprite set up then:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

--calling up sprite.lua library
local sprite = require( "sprite" )
--setting up sprite sheet
local sheet1 = sprite.newSpriteSheet( "itemSlot.png", 72, 72 )
---spriteSheet, startFrame, frameCount 
local spriteSet1 = sprite.newSpriteSet(sheet1, button1state, 4)
--Slot 1
--spriteSet, sequenceName, startFrame, frameCount, time, [loopParam] 
sprite.add( spriteSet1, "green", composer.getVariable("buttonState" ), 4)
local slot1 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )
slot1.x = 72*6  --button location left/right
slot1.y = 72*5  --button location up/down  

--Bring up Item slot Selection window
slot1.dropDown=function(event)
  if(event.phase == "ended") then
    composer.showOverlay( "scene_dropDown", options )
  end
end
slot1:addEventListener("touch",slot1.dropDown)
```

In scene_dropDown.lua

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene_game = require( "scene_game" )
local sprite = require( "sprite" )

--setting up sprite sheet
local sheet1 = sprite.newSpriteSheet( "itemSlot.png", 72, 72 )

---spriteSheet, startFrame, frameCount 
local spriteSet2 = sprite.newSpriteSet(sheet1, 1, 4)

--Item option 1
--spriteSet, sequenceName, startFrame, frameCount, time, [loopParam] 
sprite.add( spriteSet2, "green", 1,4)
local item1 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet2 )
item1.x = display.contentCenterX+36 --button location left/right
item1.y = display.contentCenterY-36 --button location up/down 
item1:setFrame( 2 )

--Item option 1 functions
function state1Cb( event )
display.remove(item1)
composer.setVariable("buttonState", 2 )
item1:removeEventListener( "tap", state1Cb )
timer.performWithDelay( 1, addListenerA )   -- Do this instead
return true   
end

--Item option 1 listener
function addListener1()
item1:addEventListener( "tap", state1Cb )
end

--Finishing up the listeners
addListener1() 
return scene
```

This is a cut back version of the code with just one option.

Answer (score 0):

In showOverlay() there should be a parameter on the event table that's the parent's scene object.  If you add functions or variables to the scene object/table then in showOverlay()'s create or show function you can do:

```
local parentScene = event.parent
parentScene.doSomething()
parentScene.someValue = 10
```

etc.